# Why is a W-16 called, well, W?

Tags: engine, engine-theory, cylinder

The term "W-16" seems to imply some sort of configuration that resembles the letter W, which implies three banks of cylinders with one sharing a common cylinder head. In fact, the Bugatti W-16 in the Veyron is probably more accurately a double-V-16, with the two V's having different angles. So...was there any reason someone (possibly the Volkswagen group) decided to call this configuration a W-16?
**Edit:** The connecting rod configuration of the Veyron W-16 from the front looks something like this:
[image: W-16 Configuration]
Not much like the letter W.

Comment: It is just like two V8s strapped together. Two engines in a V configuration (i.e. V V) make a W shape with the cylinders.

Comment: See...that's what first confused me about the "W" designation; I thought the apex of the middle of the "W" represented another cylinder head, so three in total. I think double-V would be less confusing, but that's just me.

Comment: It's kind of a fake W.  We should rename it but I don't know what we would call it.  It has a delta look.  Like a top down of an F-106 Delta Dart.  Maybe it's new name is the Double Delta.  Let's commission a marketing analysis.  Should be less $25,000 for that. Then we can sit in meetings for days debating it.   :-)

Comment: The letter "W" is only called "Double-U" in English.  Other languages, such as French, Spanish, and Italian, call this letter "Double-V."

Comment: That's quality trivia @BenMiller  :-)   I hope I don't sound like I'm minimizing it by calling it trivia either.  Love factoids like that.

Comment: @DucatiKiller Trivia, yes, but when the OP says that a French car maker should have called their engine "Double-V" instead of "W", it is relevant.

Comment: Indeed.  I think it's relative either way too.  Perhaps factoid is a better representation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert, but found an interesting article on Wikipedia about the W engine that indicates the W being a relatively recent addition to the automotive world, but not the aircraft/motorcycle worlds:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_engine

> Three different configurations have been called W engines:
>
> - Three banks of cylinders sharing a common crankshaft, a configuration also known as broad arrow configuration due to its shape resembling the British government broad arrow property mark.
> - Four banks of cylinders sharing a common crankshaft, also called a 'double-V'.
> - Two banks of cylinders with two crankshafts.
>
> [...]
>
> The classical W engine uses three banks of cylinders, all connected to
> one crankshaft.
>
> [...]
>
> One of the first W engines was the Anzani 3-cylinder, built in 1906, to be used in Anzani motorcycles.
>
> [...]
>
> The 1917 Napier Lion aircraft engine was an early W12 engine.

Most of the rest of the article calls that the W engine, and calls the Veyron engine a double-V (specifically a double-VR6) engine.

Looks like double-V started becoming known in the 1930-40 range.  There's a mention in that article of a couple double-V (W12 and W24) aircraft engines becoming known about then(in addition to DucatiKiller's mention of the Auto Union Type-C).

That Anzani 3-cylinder is the first mention that I could find of a W.  As far as that W engine, it does look like what you were mentioning
(3 cylinder banks) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anzani_3-cylinder_fan_engines. The Napier Lion looks like that too.

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner  :-)  Great research, great answer.

Answer (score 13):

**I think I know**

If you want citations, I have already failed you.

**You Asked**

> Was there any reason someone (possibly the Volkswagen group) decided to call this configuration a W-16?

**Answer**

***Maybe***.

Looking at this picture you can see the various designs and names of ICE platforms created by VW.

If you take a V and push into another V it looks like this.

**VV** Which looks like a W, hence the name.

[image]

**Trivia**

The oldest W-16 configuration that I can find is the Auto Union Type-C from 1936. Auto Union was one of the founding components of Audi AG.  Here it is.

[image]